# How to properly develop a login screen for Android app

Tags: android, authentication, subscription

I am a newbie to Android and to web programming, and I am developing an Android app.

I want to develop a subscription screen to my application and present it just for the first time the user subscribes. From that point on the user will see only the application itself.

I would like to ask you how should I start this thing? I really have no clue...

Comment: search internet for beginning Android programming tutorials. I'm sure there are a few....

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Android programming, then I highly recommend following these tutorials

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g

New Boston channel has over 200 tutorials which are all quite detailed and very well explained. Don't have to do them all, but at least the first 50-100 I would say to get a good grasp of the basics. Then once you understand the basics, then you will begin to know what to search for when developing the type of app you are trying to create.